# PHP empty table, but no errors

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search button where it search the report for the input date. But when I clicked the button The table shows empty even If I input correctly the start and end date.

PHP code

```
<?php
include('konek.php');

$start = isset($_GET['d1']) ? $_GET['d1'] : '';
$end = isset($_GET['d2']) ? $_GET['d2'] : '';

if (isset($_GET['submit']) && $_GET['submit']=='Search') {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT
        t1.qty, t2.lastname, t2.firstname, t2.date, t3.name,
        t2.reservation_id, t2.payable FROM prodinventory AS t1
             INNER JOIN reservation AS t2
             ON t1.confirmation=t2.confirmation
             INNER JOIN products AS t3
             ON t1.room=t3.id
             WHERE t2.date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'
             GROUP BY t2.confirmation");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo'<tr class="record">';
        echo'<td>'; echo $row['reservation_id'];  echo'</td>';
        echo'<td>'; echo $row['date'];  echo'</td>';
        echo'<td>'; echo $row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'];  echo'</td>';
        echo'<td>'; echo $row['name'].' '.$row['qty'];  echo'</td>';
        echo'<td>'; echo $row['payable'];  echo'</td>';
        echo'</tr>';

        echo'</tbody>';
        echo'</table>';

        $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(payable) FROM reservation WHERE date BETWEEN '$d1'    AND '$d2'");
        while ($rows1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
?>

<div class="pull-right">
    <div class="span">
        <div class="alert alert-info"><i class="icon-credit-card icon-large">    </i>&nbsp;Sub Total: PHP&nbsp;<?php echo number_format(floatval($rows1['SUM(payable)'])); ?  ></div>
    </div>
</div>
</center>
<?php }}} ?>
```

Here's my HTML form

```
<form action="salesreport.php" method="GET">
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" class="btnsearch" value="Search" />
From : <input type="text" name="d1" id="d1" class="tcal" value="" />    
To: <input type="text" name="d2" id="d2" class="tcal" value=""  />
```

Comment: First of all: did you check if your query actually returns proper result? On first peek i can see that you're using GROUP BY aggregating clause, but in select you're trying to select data not included in GROUP BY clause without using aggregate functions.

Comment: What happens if you echo out your queries? Do they look OK? Do they work when you run them in the database?

Comment: Yes it is working in my database, but in my php it does not work

Comment: Where are `$d1` and `$d2` defined? As it stands, they are stray variables.

Comment: From and To. Start and end date of my report I want to search

Comment: You haven't answered [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081679/php-empty-table-but-no-errors#comment39024112_25081679).

Comment: Plus, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Meaning this `BETWEEN '$d1' AND '$d2'` - You may have meant to use `BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'` just like the other one. There's nothing showing `$d1 = "something";` etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- +1. Adding `display_errors` and `error_reporting` should be mandatory in dev env...

Comment: @user3896397 - You should also print the SQL in the PHP code so that we all see how the date query looks...

Comment: @raidenace True. Many new coders are not aware of the (debugging) tools available. I was *once* part of the "new coders" ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know and so was/am I :) PHP is pretty notorious in how cumbersome it is to debug considering some other languages/supported IDEs

Comment: @raidenace Indeed. Many a time, OP's defaults are set to OFF. Giving them those codes ensures/overwrites the default settings for error reporting; most of the time ;) OP should be getting back errors such as "`Undefined index d1`" etc. and maybe a few others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you meant `$start` and `$end` rather than `$d1` or `$d2`:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(payable) 
                        FROM reservation 
                        WHERE date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo number_format(floatval($rows1['SUM(payable)'])); ?  >
```

Please check code. PHP close syntax for "?" and ">"